# Java - Could not find or load main class gui

Tags: java, jar

I understand that there are many similar questions and answers, but none of the answers fit what I am trying to do. I have a file called `gui.java` and I am trying to turn it into a jar file, `LifeGame.jar` I keep the .java and the .class in a folder, and when I try to archive it, it works, but when I try to run the file, it gives me `Could not find or load main class gui`. I do give a manifest called "META-INF:MANIFEST.MF" and the folder is stored on my desktop.The manifest looks like:

```
Main-Class: gui
```

I would like some advice on what to do and how to fix this problem. (As I have already said, I understand this is a clone of many other questions, but the examples I've seen don't work for me in my situation)

EDIT:

Some details on my scenario:

I have multiple classes in gui.java but only one of them is public, the rest aren't private of public. It is on my desktop and when I try `java gui` it gives the same error as when I try archiving it into a Jar.

Comment: You might have to give a lot more details about where your scenario differs from which other question on this topic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name of your main class should be *gui*. check your *.class* file which is created to be *gui.class* or any other. It doesn't matter the name of *.java* file but the name of *.class* file.